# Vibrations in Stones and Crystals

Tags: energy, particle-physics, crystals, vibrations, molecules

I have read studies done that indicate certain sounds can either disrupt or reinforce the molecular structure (I think this is the terminology used) of living organisms. This is based on the idea that specific sounds give of vibrations that either help or hurt the living organism. Therefore, I was wondering if there have been studies done that indicate certain stones or crystals give off certain vibration frequencies. OR if there is any science to either dispute or support this question?

Comment: The Wikipedia article on Crystal Healing states: "There is no peer-reviewed scientific evidence that crystal healing has any effect; it is considered a pseudoscience". The article goes on to mention studies that found no benefit of using crystals over a placebo.

Comment: TO FUTURE READERS: This isn't a bad question, but a decent question about bad science. I think we all know the answer, but let's not punish the messenger for asking an interesting question about long-debunked pseudoscience

Comment: I'm just trying to understand if there is any scientific basis for this theory. We know that certain vibrations do affect the structure of living organisms (I even conducted a study on this via plants and different music types.) Therefore I was wondering if there was any basis on the idea that things like rocks could give off certain vibrations/vibrational patterns (ones that we would not be able to pick up on unless we used advanced technology). My question is a reasonable scientific inquiry that is based on previous theories being proven.  I think to riducule this quetion is petty.

Comment: And to say that this area as been debunked please show me the research. One research experiment that has been recorded that included a 5 minute meditation period for each participant is not a very good experiment....A longitudinal study would need to be conducted and also I would imagine any serious researcher or scientist would also attempt to obtain evidence data to determine if stones do or do not emit vibrations from the every moving make-up of their substance...

Comment: I was asking for evidence to either support or dispute this question. And none of the people who blocked this question provided me with any sort of evidence. Therefore, how can it be determined to be off topic? TO just make a claim without supporting evidence or shut-down a question that was sincerely asked shows the signs of ignorant and closed minds. This is not what science facilitates. IF anything it reminds me of the ancient priests who would kill philosophers like Plato, Socrates, or Aristotle for being brave enough to ask questions that do not fit the mainstream.

Answer (score 1):

There is a certain amount of New Age mythology about stones & crystals,but the good vibes they give off are purely imaginary. Some crystals,ruby for example, can be used for Light Amplification by Stimulated Emission of Radiation,or lasers,but it's nothing to do with sound. Military research has experimented with using sound (or ultra-sound) as a weapon,as humans are very sensitive to some frequencies if they are loud enough. They can incapacitate you for a while,but I have never heard of any that are lethal. They might be useful for riot control,except they can't differentiate between rioters & innocent passers by. There is a civilian application called The Mosquito which generates a sound which teenagers find very unpleasant & has the useful property that older people can't hear it (when I was 5 years old I could hear bats,when I was 15 I could hear the high pitched,musical trill of grasshopper warblers,but by the age of 35 I could only hear the warblers as a faint,grasshopper-type sound). The device is used to prevent teenagers loitering near shopping centres where they cause a nuisance.

Comment: in your last offer I thought you were discussing mosquito sound repellers, which mosquito do not like but humans cannot hear :)

Comment: No it was teenager repellent,based on sound. Teenagers tend to hang around shopping precincts in trouble-making gangs,& the device makes a sound which teenagers cannot bear,but adults can't hear it. I am familiar with mozzie reppelant;we used to use it in the jungle. We found it didn't work well with mozzies,but was just the job for fending off land leeches,which are very troublesome in some parts of the rainforest.